# http-server doesnt work and doesnt display file

Tags: node.js, httpserver

I want to work with node and use [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server).
But somehow instead of hosting a local http server with the html file I choose, it just starts a download on the given IP.
It's the HTML file but without the html extension and its just called File.
I really dont know why this is happening - especially because it always worked just fine.

EDIT:
What I did :
I used the command `http-server index.html` and the given IP didnt displayed my html file but instead just let me download my html file.

Comment: Please give a [mre].

Comment: Well, I use 'http-server index.html' 
get the IP the server is hosting on
Try to connect and instead of showing the HTML file it just starts a Download.

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the required information. Also see [ask].